# Pointcut on annotated method

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, aspect

I'm trying to add a custom annotation for JPA repository methods to have a advice on @Query value.

Below is the piece of code I tried

MyFilter class

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyFilter {
   @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @within(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query)")
   private void createQuery(){}

   @Around("createQuery()")
   public void invoke(JointPoint jp) {
   }
}
```

The Respository code

```
@MyFilter
@Query(Select * ...)
MyObject findByNameAndClass(...)
```

So I keep getting error

```
createQuery() is never called At MyFilter
```

I'm trying to update the Query value using the advice.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `@MyFilter` supposed to mean or do? Your pseudo code does not explain it, but the aspect is named after it without relating to it at all. It would be nice if you could at least explain what you want to achieve. Your empty aspect advice and `...` instead of actual code are not helping either. Please learn how to ask questions, if you hope for spot-on answers. Otherwise - garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: hey @kriegaex, my question has nothing to do with what @MyFilter does, my sole problem was with the pointcut as mentioned in the title. I think I have got my spot-on answers from `@p3consulting` and `@DotNetRussell`. Many Thanks to them I was able to resolve my issue. Both the answers helped me. I think if the question was garbage in, garbage out they wouldn't be able to help. Going forward I'll keep in mind your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Then why don't you remove that annotation from your sample code and rename the aspect. It is named `MyFilterAspect`, so obviously I was expecting the aspect to be related to that annotation. See, that is the result of posting incomplete code snippets instead of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody can reproduce your problem, which could have all kinds of root causes. Therefore, nobody can help you by any other means than educated guesses or pure speculation.

Comment: Besides, under all those correct answers you first commented that they did **not** help you. Only later you wrote that they did. So the problem was not just the wrong pointcut but something else, too. Otherwise, I would not have commented here. It was obvious that something else was missing, but you did not say what. If you had described better what you want or or posted more code, showing which of the two annotations you want to capture and what you want to do with it, I could have answered your question in 2 minutes without having to guess.

Comment: Sure will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the annotation I often use this pattern:

```
 "execution(@AnnotationToCapture * *(..)) && @annotation(annotationParam)"
```

Then in the proceeding method, you can have the annotation as parameter:

```
(..., AnnotationToCapture annotationParam, ...)
```

Comment: updated it to `execution(@org.springframewowrk.data.jpa.repository.Query * *(..)) && @annotation(query)` this isn't helping. Firstly, I keep getting error unresolved param query. If you can elaborate your solution, I would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Around("execution(@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query * *(..)) && @annotation(queryAnn)")
   public void applyFilter(JointPoint jp, Query queryAnn) {
   }

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `@within` annotation for this purpose. Instead, you should use `@annotation`, as follows:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query)")
private void createQuery(){}
```

Also, you should use JoinPoint to access the method signature and then you can extract the annotation from the signature.

Comment: Hey, I tried updating as you suggested yet facing same problem. Also, what do you mean by `you should use JoinPoint to access the method signature and then you can extract the annotation from the signature`? I'm new to AOP would really appreciate you help on this.

Comment: hey @DotNetRussell, thanks for your solution. Your mention of Jointpoint helped me. I read about it and solved my later issues.